# Limit of startupeventargs.args array?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 14 arguments being passed into through command line. However first one seems to be cut off for some reason and isn't reaching into startupeventargs.args.

What is the size of StartupEventArgs e  string array?

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    ParseArguments(e.Args);
}

private static void ParseArguments(string[] args)
{
    //args[args.Length + 1] = "-sn";

    Log.Write("Parsing {0} arguments...", args.Length);

    // Parse the command line arguments
    for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        //test Log.Write(args[i]);
        switch (args[i - 1])
        {
            case "-sn":
                // Parse the show name
                ShowName = args[i];
                break;

//...
```

EDIT:
it is called from another app written in c++:

```
sprintf(szCommandLine, "-sn %n -sd %s -w %d -h %d -t %d -l %d -th %d", 
    szWebShow, szBaseDir, iWidth, iHeight, iTop, iLeft, threadID);

if(CreateProcess(PLAYWEB_EXE,szCommandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
                 DETACHED_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &startInfo, &procInfo)) {
    Log(LOGSTR("Web Show Started: %s ", szCommandLine));
```

command line:
(path to .exe) -sn "M000018\33.9999-2815-8-WS001" -sd c:\Player\Shows2 -w 1280 -h 720 -t 0 -l 0 th 1

Comment: Check you access first item like this: `e.Args[0]` (because arrays are zero based) or within foreach loop

Comment: i added how i parse it

Comment: Show how you call it from the command line, is it something simple like missing quotes?

Comment: So which part is being cut off exactly? Did you inspect `args` with a debugger to see if it's really missing some data?

Comment: the "-sn" part is missing and yes i did

Comment: "-sn" is at index 0, the "M000018\33.9999-2815-8-WS001" is at index 1, "-sd" is at index 2, etc

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C# are zero based, from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287879(v=vs.71).aspx):

> C# arrays are zero indexed; that is, the array indexes start at zero

The array index needs to start at 0:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
{
    //.....
```

**EDIT**

Now you have added the explanation of how you are calling the process, I can see you have an issue with it. From the docs on the [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) function, the second parameter is the command line and:

> If both *lpApplicationName* and *lpCommandLine* are non-NULL, the null-terminated string pointed to by lpApplicationName specifies the module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by lpCommandLine specifies the command line.

What you should be doing is something like this:

```
CreateProcess(NULL, szCommandLine....)
```

Where `szCommandLine` has the executable prefix, for example `PLAYWEB_EXE -sn blah... etc`

Comment: switch (args[i - 1])  <<This makes it start at 0.